# How is zorder used in matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to understand some code and in the code zorder is sometimes set to -1 and other times 100. I am very confused what zorder does, I tried reading the documentation but I still don't get it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Keep in mind that the idea of [Z-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order) is used in many places beyond matplotlib. If you think of the page as 2D, the z-order determines where along the z-axis an object lies on that page. An item at `z=-1` will be shown above an item at `z=-2`. An item at `z=50` will be below an item at `z=100`.

Answer (score 3):

zorder specifies the order in which the various components of a plot are layered on top of each other.  Consider the following code and corresponding graph.  Notice how the mortality line plot is showing as the front layer over the the two bar plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

months = ["March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"]
cases = [1000, 2000, 5000, 8000, 15000, 6000]
hosp = [n*0.1 for n in cases]
deaths = [n*0.03 for n in cases]

month_indexes = np.arange(len(months))
WIDTH = 0.25

plt.bar(month_indexes - WIDTH, cases, width=WIDTH, color="orange", label="All cases")
plt.bar(month_indexes, hosp, width=WIDTH, color="blue", label="Hospitalizations")
plt.plot(month_indexes + WIDTH, deaths, color="red", label="Deaths")

plt.title("Cases and Mortality")
plt.legend(loc = "upper center", bbox_to_anchor = (0.2, 1.0), fancybox = True, shadow = True)
plt.xticks(month_indexes,months)
plt.ylim(top=max(cases))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Now let's say you want to move the red line behind the blue bars but in front of the orange bars.  You can simply assign a positive or negative zorder to each plot.  The greater the z-order, the more "in front" the plot is drawn.

```
plt.bar(month_indexes - WIDTH, cases, width=WIDTH, color="orange", label="All cases", zorder = 1)
plt.bar(month_indexes, hosp, width=WIDTH, color="blue", label="Hospitalizations", zorder = 3)
plt.plot(month_indexes + WIDTH, deaths, color="red", label="Deaths", zorder = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Does the relative order of the code determines the `zorder`? Or do some commands have higher "priority"? For example, `plt.plot; plt.scatter` first draws the scatter and then the line plot.